# Rails ActiveRecord Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'objectname.'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an update to an existing MySQL table that is failing under Rails.  Here's the relevant controller code:

```
on = ObjectName.find_by_object_id(params[:id])
if (on) #edit existing
  if on.update_attributes(params[:param_type] => params[:value])
    respond_to do |format|
      ...
end
```

The ObjectName model class has 3 values (object_id, other_id, and prop1).  When the update occurs, the SQL generated is coming out as

```
UPDATE `objectname` SET `other_id` = 245 WHERE `objectname`.`` IS NULL
```

The `SET` portion of the generated SQL is correct.  Why is the `WHERE` clause being set to ``` .`` IS NULL ``` ?

Comment: What is `mti` and how the title is connected with the content of your question?

Comment: `mti` was a misspelling on my part.  I've corrected it.  I've also corrected the title.  That's the error I'm receiving when this code is exectuted.

Comment: what does `ObjectName.primary_key` returns?

Comment: It all depends on what is your `params[:param_type]` is. Because that part of the SQL is populated by the value of this param.

Comment: nil, although the table itself has a compound PK on the 2 _id fields.

Comment: `params[:param_type]` is `other_id`

Comment: What do you use to support compound PK? Is it a real compound PK, or pseudo PK with uniq index on both fields?

Comment: I'm not sure that we previously had support for it.  I've downloaded http://compositekeys.rubyforge.org/ and attempting to use that.  So far, that's failing for me as well.

Comment: Installed composite_primary_keys gem, but I'm still not seeing the primary key listed and the SQL output remains unchanged.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same error when working with a table with no primary key defined. There was a unique key set up on the field but no PK.  Setting the PK in the model fixed it for me:

```
self.primary_key = :object_id
```

Comment: Tim, you saved my life. Was stuck for hours.